# Correct use of the verb "poll"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality

Say there are 100 factors that determine the outcome of a process. Some of them are simple and easy to observe, while others are very intricate. Is the following sentence correct?

> The experiment should determine which of the 100 factors can be
>   efficiently **polled** through a questionnaire.

Comment: What do you intend *polled* to mean? If you had to replace that word with something else, what would you use?

Comment: @Andrew Leach: My guess is that "questioned" is that something else.

Comment: @Frank You need to explain in more detail what your intention is with regard to your sentence. What is the relationship between the questionnaire and the 100 factors? Are there a hundred questions in the questionnaire? Or are the hundred factors determined by asking a set of questions? Or is the experiment the questionnaire?

Comment: @Baz and Andrew: Sorry for the late response. "Polled" in the example is intended to mean something like "can be asked from the test subject". For example, a test subject can give his age and height (two of the 100 factors) through a questionnaire, but maybe not his pulse response to a specific external shock.

Comment: @Frank We'll then you should go with Lynn's answer as it hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically it's correct, but I think you see from the disjointed answers that it's not readily clear what point you're trying to get across.   Poll can have an engineering meaning or a survey meaning, and the survey meaning is not often used in an intransitive sense like "can be polled through..."   I would reword it to something more like this:

> The experiment should determine which of the 100 factors can be efficiently *assessed* through a questionnaire.

Comment: I agree your suggested *assessed* is a better word in OP's context, but I don't agree there's any real doubt about what the original version means. If you want to split hairs, you could say OP might mean anything between *established* (i.e. - determined to a high level of precision) all the way to *worded* (i.e. - capable of being phrased and asked in a questionnaire in such a way that the results might feasibly have some significance). In practice I think those differences are somewhat academic, but *assessed* at least leaves them all open.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I mostly agree.  It seemed pretty clear to  me but it just sounded kind of awkward.  And others appear to have had different interpretations.

Comment: I don't see anyone else saying it could mean something different *in OP's context*. SF's (now deleted) answer focussed on the exact meaning of *efficiently*, while Baz simply takes issue with this "creative" use of **poll**, which he's more familiar with in a software context. I'm not saying **polled** is "correct" here - just that it doesn't seem particularly ambiguous to me. But I agree it could be called "awkward".

Answer (score 1):

I guess its grammatically correct but I don't like the use of polled in this context. The word polled is often used in engineering. For example, "the signal is polled by the function". As an engineer, I get a little confused when I see the word used in a "new" way.

Also, I think "easily" is a better word with regard to your use of "efficiently". Again, "efficiently polled" sounds so technical and therefore distracting and confusing. You want to be clear here, not overly verbose.

Perhaps I have misunderstood the idea you wish to convey, but how about rephrasing the sentence like this instead:

> Using a questionaire, the experiment should determine which of the 100 factors are easily established.

Comment: I agree that 'polled' doesn't really fit, but I think you've misunderstood the original idea of the sentence.

Comment: How do you interpret the original meaning?

Comment: I think the question is more:  "Which of the factors can be determined *with a* questionnaire." Your reword made me think that the question was about which factors are easily established, period.